# Couchbase | How to reduce select query execution time when the document size is 5 MB

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

Couchbase | How to reduce select query execution time when the document size is 5 MB.

Problem: Bellow Select Query takes 16000 ms. How to reduce the execution time of this query.
But If I use findById It only takes 4000ms. Because of primary key.

Note : result field has 5MB text content. Hashcode is a secondary index column.

Question 1: If I create a view with only having id & hash code, and then query that view. Will that speed-up ?

**index creation script**

```
create index matrix_hashcode on price (_class, hashcode )
     where _class = "com.intervest.price.oxygen.model.ClientMatrix"
     USING GSI;
```

repository code

```
public List<ClientMatrix> findByHashcode(int hashcode);//16000 ms
public List<ClientMatrix> findById(int id);//4000 ms
```

Couchbase Entity

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
public class ClientMatrix {

    @Id
    @Field
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private int hashcode;

    @Field
    private String token;

    @Field
    private String request;

    @Field
    private List<com.intervest.price.oxygen.model.ClientMatrixPriceResultGroup> result=new ArrayList<>();

    @Field
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
}
```

---

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
@JsonPropertyOrder({"supportedValues","results"})
public class ClientMatrixPriceResultGroup {


    @Id
    private Long resultId;

    @Field
    private Long requestId;

    @Field
    @JsonProperty("filtering-criteria")
    private SortedMap supportedValues=new TreeMap();
    @Field
    private List<com.intervest.price.oxygen.model.ClientMatrixPriceResult> results=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<com.intervest.price.oxygen.model.ClientMatrixPriceResult> getResults() {
    return results;
    }
```

[image: sample document]

Comment: Do you have any insight into what N1QL is being created and/or which indexes are being used? Whenever there's a "slow query", the problem is usually "querying for too many records" or "index can be improve"

Comment: @MatthewGroves But If I use findById It only takes 4000ms. Because of the primary key.

Comment: Looking up a document by key will *always* be fastest. Looking it up with a secondary index requires the query service and index service. Which is why you need to focus on the index. What indexes have you created?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I have added to script to Question now

Comment: You should use covering secondary index. CREATE INDEX ix1 bucket(hashcode); SELECT META().id, hashcode FROM bucket WHERE hashcode = "xyz";

Answer (score 0):

When used secondary index with 5MB documents the data needs to do 2 hops
 (DATA Node ==> N1QL ===>Client)

You can use covered secondary index find the document key as follows.

```
CREATE INDEX matrix_hashcode ON price ( hashcode )
WHERE _class = "com.intervest.price.oxygen.model.ClientMatrix";
SELECT META(p).id, p.hashcode 
FROM price AS p
WHERE p._class = "com.intervest.price.oxygen.model.ClientMatrix" AND p.hashcode = "xyz";
```

Once you have document key you can use SDKs to get the document. You can also use SDK subdoc to get the required fields.